# replacing values in XSLT using xsl:choose function

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I have already managed transofrmation from XML to CSV using XSLT. I am attaching just part of the XSLT to make it simplier.
I just would like to add functionality which will replace values of "ConsentCode" as following: YES->1, NO->0, NOTSET-> "" (empty string).
I assume that this can be done using "xsl:choose" function but I did not managed to adapt it to my XSLT
Could you please advice?
Thank you

**Here is my XML**

```
    <SiebelMessage>
    <ListOfSwiOrganizationIO>
        <Account>
            <Id>F-8LU</Id>
            <PartyUId>A0A047</PartyUId>
            <Email>de2@sk.ds.com</Email>
            <Name>DBEXT2</Name>         
            <ListOfIntegrityCode>
                <IntegrityCode>
                    <IntegrityType>AllowSms</IntegrityType>
                    <ConsentCode>YES</ConsentCode>
                </IntegrityCode>
                <IntegrityCode>
                    <IntegrityType>AllowEmail</IntegrityType>
                    <ConsentCode>NO</ConsentCode>
                </IntegrityCode>
            </ListOfIntegrityCode>          
        </Account>
    </ListOfSwiOrganizationIO>
</SiebelMessage>
```

**Here is my XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="';'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Integrity Codes -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ListOfIntegrityCode/IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowSms']/ConsentCode, $delimiter, ListOfIntegrityCode/IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowEmail']/ConsentCode, $delimiter)"/>
        <!-- end values --> 

        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Output in CSV:**
1,0

Comment: Well what does `NOTSET-> "" (empty string)` mean exactly? If the `ConsentCode` is emtpy, then you want to output an empty string, or if the `ConsentCode` element does not exist, then you want to output an empty string. Generally I would define a variable with a mapping and function that maps each input value to the output value based on the mapping, then you could simply call that function. And while `xsl:choose` exists, XSLT/XPath 2.0 also have an `if (condition) then expression1 else expresssion2` conditional expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you wanted to do it with an **xsl::choose** you might be better off placing the logic in a named-template you then call multiple times:

```
<xsl:template name="ConsentCode">
   <xsl:param name="code" />
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$code = 'YES'">1</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$code = 'NO'">0</xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you would output your line like so

```
    <xsl:call-template name="ConsentCode">
        <xsl:with-param name="code" select="ListOfIntegrityCode/IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowSms']/ConsentCode" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" /> 
    <xsl:call-template name="ConsentCode">
        <xsl:with-param name="code" select="ListOfIntegrityCode/IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowEmail']/ConsentCode" />
    </xsl:call-template>
```

On the other hand, if you are using XSLT 2.0, you can remove the **xsl:choose** and use this expression instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="if ($code = 'YES') then '1' else (if ($code = 'NO') then '0' else '')" />
```

And if you obscure coding is your thing, you could code it like this, which would work in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($code, 'YNESO', '10')" />
```